# Error Push Git to gitlab error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly

Tags: git, gitlab

I try to migrate my project on new project gitlab.com
but i have this error. i try to increease the buffer but don't work

i increases the buffer at 1,5 go. but Error RPC

```js
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

$ git push gitlab --mirror
Enumerating objects: 365, done.
Counting objects: 100% (365/365), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (223/223), done.
error: unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly| 0 bytes/s
Writing objects: 100% (365/365), 1.11 GiB | 66.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 365 (delta 121), reused 365 (delta 121), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

$ git push gitlab
Enumerating objects: 365, done.
Counting objects: 100% (365/365), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (223/223), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedlyB | 3.00 KiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (365/365), 1.11 GiB | 94.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 365 (delta 121), reused 365 (delta 121), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

$ git config --global http.postBuffer 1572864000

$ git push gitlab --mirror
Enumerating objects: 365, done.
Counting objects: 100% (365/365), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (223/223), done.
Writing objects: 100% (365/365), 1.11 GiB | 72.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 365 (delta 121), reused 365 (delta 121), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Do you have a broken proxy, firewall, antivirus, or SSL MITM device?  You should never see that message with modern software.

Comment: no proxy, Avast antivirus, I use my personal internet box, I pushed another smaller project, i try to increases the buffer to 1572864000 but never end

Comment: Wow! A git repo of **1.11 GiB** size! Of course a 150MB++ of buffer won't fit that much. Did you commit a movie or two in your git repo? Maybe you are using git for a wrong purpose?

Comment: Git should normally use chunked transfer encoding for large pushes, and this works fine unless you have a broken box that doesn't support HTTP/1.1 properly.  Avast has a feature to tamper with encrypted connections which might be breaking things here, so I'd recommend completely removing it, restarting, using Windows Defender instead, and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: with out Avast is Work think

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything, nothing worked for me.
degrading the http.version is the only way that worked for me
downgrade version of HTTP from 2 to 1.1:

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

After you push changed HTTP version to 2 again:

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried;

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1  
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

even,

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

[image: failed example]

but,  nothing changed. I had two folders with this error. one with 10MB size and one with 65MB.

finally.
**I tried with a Fibre connection.**

[image: worked proof]

So yeah. try with a different, higher speed connection. probably it will work.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Answer (score -6):

uninstall Avast, and use Windows defender